# How to specify the position information of a node - on which line, when inserting a new node using babel

Tags: babeljs, code-coverage

here is my resource code

```js
const a = 1 + 2;
function Controller() {
    console.log('hi');
}
```

I wanna to convert it to as following by babel

```js
const a = 1 + 2;log();
function Controller() {
    console.log('hi');
}
```

I try to use replaceWithSourceString, but is error

```js
childrenPath.replaceWithSourceString(childrenPath.toString() + 'log()');
```